# Calling Graphi API from Classic JavaScript through msal.js

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online, azure-ad-graph-api, azure-ad-msal, msal.js

I am trying to do silent login through msal.js and then trying to call graph api but always I get 403 error. When I decrypt my access token through jwt.ms I can see that audience is correct but scopes are showing wrong. Hope some can help me.

My code

```
let config = {
    auth: {
      clientId: _spPageContextInfo.spfx3rdPartyServicePrincipalId,
      authority: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${_spPageContextInfo.aadTenantId}`,
      redirectUri: 'https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/xxx-Dev/Pages/myportal.aspx',
      validateAuthority: false,
      postLogoutRedirectUri: window.origin,
    },
    cache: {
      cacheLocation: 'localStorage',
      storeAuthStateInCookie: true
    }
  }

  let myMSALObj = new Msal.UserAgentApplication(config)
  let graphConfig = {
    graphGroupEndpoint: "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups"
  }

  let request = {
    scopes: ["https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"]
  }


  myMSALObj.handleRedirectCallback(response => { console.log(response) });
  //const idTokenScope = { scopes: [_spPageContextInfo.spfx3rdPartyServicePrincipalId] }

  const handleError = (error) => {
    if (error.errorCode === 'consent_required'
      || error.errorCode === 'interaction_required'
      || error.errorCode === 'login_required') {
      //myMSALObj.loginRedirect(idTokenScope);
      myMSALObj.loginRedirect(request);
      return;
    }
    throw error;
  };

  const getToken = () => {
    const date = new Date();
    const user = myMSALObj.getAccount();
    if (!user) {
      //myMSALObj.loginRedirect(idTokenScope);
      myMSALObj.loginRedirect(request);
      return;
    }
    //myMSALObj.acquireTokenSilent(idTokenScope).then(response => {
    myMSALObj.acquireTokenSilent(request).then(response => {
      console.log(`${date.toLocaleTimeString()}`, response.accessToken);
      callMSGraph(graphConfig.graphGroupEndpoint, response.accessToken, graphAPICallback)
    }).catch(handleError);
  }
  getToken()

  function callMSGraph(theUrl, accessToken, callback) {
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest()
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200)
        callback(JSON.parse(this.responseText))
    }
    xmlHttp.open("GET", theUrl, true)
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + accessToken)
    xmlHttp.send()
  }
  function graphAPICallback(data) {
    document.write(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2))
  }
```

My decoded token
[image]

My app permission
[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are two kinds of permissions: one is application permission, the othre one is delegated permission.  And "`https://graph.microsoft.com/.default`" is for application permisisons.

[image]

With interactively signning from browser, you will be asked to provided with your credentials.  In this way, you will get an access token for yourself, which is with delegated permissions. We call this as [OAuth 2.0 authorization code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow)

However, as you do not set any required delegated permission in your request scope, Azure AD just return you an access token with basic delegated permissions (openid, email an profile).

---

By the way, if you just want to get an access token with application permissions. You just need to use the [OAuth 2.0 client credentials flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow#get-a-token) to get a token.